# group variables depending on defined circular area with center of circle having variable radius

Tags: r, data.table, subset, geometry

I have a data table object:

```
> dput(head(trackdatacompvar))
structure(list(wellvid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A4-009", 
"B3-006", "B4-015", "C2-009", "C2-034", "C3-017", "C4-014", "C4-016", 
"C4-026", "C4-036"), class = "factor"), TRACK_ID = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("Si_induced", "Si_notinduced"), class = "factor"), 
    A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X = c(50.216, 50.216, 50.091, 
    50.091, 50.216, 50.216), Y = c(295.609, 295.609, 295.477, 
    295.477, 295.609, 295.609), T = 0:5, V = c(0, 0, 0.181793839279557, 
    0, 0.181793839279557, 0), x_grpA = c(641.67, 641.67, 641.67, 
    641.67, 641.67, 641.67), y_grpA = c(625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 
    625), rad_grpA = c(50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L), x_grpB = c(889.58, 
    889.58, 889.58, 889.58, 889.58, 889.58), y_grpB = c(377.08, 
    377.08, 377.08, 377.08, 377.08, 377.08), rad_grpB = c(20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L)), .Names = c("wellvid", "TRACK_ID", 
"treatment", "A", "X", "Y", "T", "V", "x_grpA", "y_grpA", "rad_grpA", 
"x_grpB", "y_grpB", "rad_grpB"), sorted = "wellvid", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000210788>)
```

I want to define 4 groups of data depending on circular area. Groups A and B will be dependent on the x,y origin of 2 beads (labelled as x_grpA, y_grpA and x_grpB, y_grpB), group C is an outside area and group D as the area where groups A and B overlap (but this area is sometimes not there). The 2 circular groups should be inside a circular area with radius of 115 µm. This 115 µm is dependent on the size of the bead, so I also have in my data 2 radius (rad_grpA and rad_grpB). To understand it visually, here are 2 pictures:

[image: Groups A, B and C]

[image: now with Group D]

My original idea is to reuse the awesome script I was given [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834964/identifying-and-subsetting-data-points-per-variable-on-concentric-circles). So, I tried defining the center of the each data point and the corresponding length of the whole area of group A as:

```
center_grpA <- c(trackdatacompvar$x_grpA, trackdatacompvar$y_grpA)
circle_grpA <- (trackdatacompvar$rad_grpA)*2 + 115
```

But after this I am lost. 
In the end I want to put inside my dataframe their grouping as one variable. 
Would appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a little convenience function from a package of mine [here](https://github.com/Ax3man/trackr/blob/master/R/trigonometry.R#L143):

```
check_if_in_circle <- function(points, x, y, r) {
  (points[, 1] - x) ^ 2 + (points[, 2] - y) ^ 2 < r ^ 2
}
```

Now we check for each point, whether it's in circle A, circle B, and then `ifelse` to figure out whether to assign A, B, C or D. I use `within` to avoid typing that long data name.

```
trackdatacompvar <- within(trackdatacompvar,
                           { 
                             grpA <- check_if_in_circle(points = cbind(X, Y), 
                                                        x_grpA, y_grpA, rad_grpA + 115)
                             grpB <- check_if_in_circle(points = cbind(X, Y), 
                                                        x_grpB, y_grpB, rad_grpB + 115)
                             grp <- ifelse(grpA, ifelse(grpB, 'D', 'A'),
                                           ifelse(grpB, 'B', 'C'))
                           } )
```

For the few rows you gave us, all are in group C.

Comment: Sorry for the example, it was just the heading of a large data frame (~750k data points). I am getting TRUE or FALSE statements for grpA and grpB, should it be the case? Because what I wanted is to have the group as a single column variable. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you can just use the last grp column, and ignore grpA and grpB. The example is fine.

Comment: I missed the grp column! Thanks again! :)